# ActiveModel Serializer JSON Includes "attributes" Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, serialization

I'm using the [Rails ActiveModel Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to output JSON to an API endpoint.

I'm getting this JSON output:

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "id":"396",
      "type":"profiles",
      "attributes":{
        "name":"Impossibles",
        "created-at":"2017-05-11T18:14:06.201-04:00",
        "updated-at":"2018-04-01T13:34:15.905-04:00",
        "website":"http://soundcloud.com/impossibles"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But was expecting it to be formatted like this:

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "id":"396",
      "type":"profiles",
      "name":"Impossibles",
      "created-at":"2017-05-11T18:14:06.201-04:00",
      "updated-at":"2018-04-01T13:34:15.905-04:00",
      "website":"http://soundcloud.com/impossibles"
    }
  ]
}
```

Trying to avoid the extra level of nesting in the returned JSON.
Is there a way to remove the "attributes" key?

This is my serializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :name, :created_at, :updated_at, :website
end
```

And my controller:

```
def show
  profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  render json: profile, status: :ok
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through some GitHub issues, it appears the "attributes" nesting is coming from the JSON API spec and *is* expected behavior:
https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects

This issue was helpful:
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/2202

Looks like a feature, not a bug.

Comment: If you don't want to conform to JSON API specification, you can always change your adapter to `json`, see [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/adapters.md).

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej thanks! Didn't realize there were two JSON adapters.